# which line(s) of code in the lay out manager invoke (call) method onBindViewHolde (MyViewHolder holder, int position)r?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

In this Android developer document https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java , the annotation of the method onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) in the  MyAdapter class reads:
// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)

My question is: which line(s) of code in the lay out manager invoke (call) this method?

[image: invoked by the layout manager]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During layout phase [`onLayoutChildren (RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager#onLayoutChildren(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Recycler,%20androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.State)) is called.

Provided [`Recycler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Recycler) is used to call [`getViewForPosition (int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Recycler#getViewForPosition(int)) which internally manages cached view pool and triggers adapters `onCreateViewHolder` (if there's no view to reuse) and `onBindViewHolder` to return `View` that's ready to be added to view hierarchy.

There are also prefetching mechanisms - [`collectAdjacentPrefetchPositions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager#collectAdjacentPrefetchPositions(int,%20int,%20androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.State,%20androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager.LayoutPrefetchRegistry)) and [`collectInitialPrefetchPositions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager#collectInitialPrefetchPositions(int,%20androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager.LayoutPrefetchRegistry)) which are used to create and bind viewholders in anticipation of currently ongoing scroll.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please fix the typo "Ther are"? I would like to archive the answer, and want it to be perfect. Also, could you please show those lines of code?

Comment: @sunyaer there aren't really "lines of code" since `LayoutManager` is an abstract class and it's up to implementations to invoke them. You're free to look through [`LinearLayoutManger` source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/237c8946756af4b0fe9d0fa3965593e247d53698/recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager.java#2227) which is the "primary" implementation but it's rather complex.